# How to loop each thread with unique data from CSV Data Config file

Tags: jmeter

I have CSV data config file with 25 users. When I create a Thread group of 25 users I want each  thread to pick one line from CSV Data config and loop around.

So

```
User1 picks userA
Users2 pick userB.......userN pick user(SomeX)
```

As I set keep alive so I want to reuse the connection and same set of data on the same socket.

```
My CSV file Recycle on EOF False
Stop Thread on EOF True
Sharing Mode : Current Thread.
```

But what I observed is `Thread 1-1 User1 picks UserA ( iteration 1)`
`Thread 1-1 User 1 picks User B  iteration 2`

What I expect is

```
Thread 1-1 User1 picks UserA ( iteration 1)
Thread 1-1 User 1 picks User A ( iteration 2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your description each JMeter thread will read CSV file independently and separately, i.e.:

- `Thread 1-1` will process all 25 CSV entries defined number of iterations
- `Thread 1-2` will process all 25 CSV entries defined number of iterations
- etc.

Given you have equal number of lines in CSV file and virtual users it might be better idea setting "Sharing mode" to `All threads` so each virtual user could pick its own line from the CSV file.

More information:

- [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
- [CSV Data Set Config in Sharing Mode - Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy)

Comment: Hello Dmitri.. My requirement is Thread 1-1 always use the first row and loop forever  and Thread 1-2 should use row 2 and loop for ever. But what I observe is the Thread 1-1 reading all the 25 rows. As I use keep-alive connection and want to read the data for this specific user only.

Comment: Please can some one help me on this.Iam stuck@Dimitri T

Answer (score 0):

Put your CSV file in an "Once Only Controller". This way the CSV will be read once for each Thread in the Thread Group.

[image: Once Only Controller in JMeter]